# what does jQuery(function) do

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am reading `javascript` web application and the author is using following code:

```
mod.load = function(func){
    $($.proxy(func, this));
};
```

Can someone help me to understand why returning function from `jQuery.proxy` is inside `jQuery` wrapper.

Is this the same as:

```
mod.load = function(func){
    var temp = $.proxy(func, this);
    temp();
};
```

Comment: yes both are similar. 
`$.proxy(func, this)` must returning function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not the same but they have the same effect. Your second example executes the returned function directly while jQuery(function) binds it to the onload like `$(document).ready()`. mod.load probably *is* the onload however, so this makes no difference.

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3

Answer (score 1):

Calling [$()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3) with a function argument is equivalent to applying [$(document).ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) to that function: it waits for the DOM to be ready before calling it.

Therefore, in your second example, `temp()` may be called before the DOM is ready, depending on the moment when `mod.load()` itself runs.

Comment: i think then it is even bad practice using $() , if i am already loading my modules after dom ready.

Answer (score 0):

Is the same, is just a shorthand.